# Appending string to label give ... at the right end

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uilabel

I am new to iPhone application development. I have a label which will get strings added at right end. When the limit exceeds the extra characters are shown as `...`. I would prefer those dots at left end. How to change this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the lineBreakMode:

```
UILabel *label = ...;
[label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation];
```